# Can anyone explain why a section isn't centering on my page?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a few elements on my page vertically and horizontally, but for some reason, setting the container element to have a margin of auto isn't centering them.  Can anyone explain why?

**HTML/CSS**

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#links{
 margin: auto;
}

.link{
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 2%;
 width: 15vw;
 height: 15vw;
 border: 2px solid rgb(100, 100, 0);
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-image: url("line.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 background-position: center;
 background-color: rgb(0, 0, 50);
}

.link:first-of-type{
 margin-left: 0;
}

.link:last-of-type{
 margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="landingpage">
    <section id="links">
        <div class="link" id="home"></div>
        <div class="link" id="work"></div>
        <div class="link" id="contact"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

[Pen](https://codepen.io/RobbyT15/pen/BZjyrv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `inline-block` you center with `text-align`. Also, your `#links` has no width and is `display: block`, so it is 100% wide.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEogXY

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#links{
 text-align: center;
}

.link{
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 2%;
 width: 15vw;
 height: 15vw;
 border: 2px solid rgb(100, 100, 0);
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: rgb(0, 0, 50);
}

.link:first-of-type{
 margin-left: 0;
}

.link:last-of-type{
 margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="landingpage">
    <section id="links">
        <div class="link" id="home"></div>
        <div class="link" id="work"></div>
        <div class="link" id="contact"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this CSS should do what you need. Using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` with a `vertical-align: middle` will allow you to center it both vertically and horizontally.

```css
#landingpage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}

#links{
    margin: auto;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#landingpage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}

#links{
    margin: auto;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.link{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 2%;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 15vw;
    border: 2px solid rgb(100, 100, 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url("line.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 50);
}

.link:first-of-type{
    margin-left: 0;
}

.link:last-of-type{
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="landingpage">
    <section id="links">
        <div class="link" id="home"></div>
        <div class="link" id="work"></div>
        <div class="link" id="contact"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owbgQp

Answer (score 0):

```css
#link{
    margin : auto;
    text-align : center;
}
```

Do the following additions.
When you apply `display:inline-block` on the children elements, they act as a text and by default align themselves in left align.
But what I have done will pass on this property to all the children elements, so if in case you want any of the children elements to align left or right, you may mention that in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

since you want to center your links horzontally and **veritically** I suggest to go with the flexbox layout. otherwise vertical alignment would only be possible using `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` or setting margins for fixed heights.

here is a codepen that illustrates the use of the flexbox layout.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqVwJp

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal centering make **#links**`display:inline-block` or give it a fixed width. And for vertical centering there is no simple way. Make your parent div `position:relative` and make #links `position:absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`.  Using table AND/OR table cell is not always good technique.